# How to organize a session at a conference?

Tags: conference, service-activities

I was recently asked by the cluster chair
to organize a session at a conference on topic X.
How does one go about organizing a conference session?

Comment: I imagine that depends a lot on the conference.

Comment: It also depends strongly on the academic discipline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my field, applied mathematics, this would mean *find 4-8 people who are willing to participate in the conference and give a talk in your session. Small print: they are going to have to pay their own conference fee, and we do not reimburse any expense to them or give financial support of any kind.*

Typically you find these people by asking them in person or sending them an e-mail. Do not overbook, as people accept more often than not, if it is a good conference.

This is how most conference sessions are organized -- if the conference itself is respectable, there is nothing suspicious about it.